# How can I get the IServiceProvider from a class library where the serviceProvider is builded in startup.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I inject some service in `Startup.cs` of a Asp.Net Core Web. It looks like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IStaffService, StaffService>();

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
 }
```

And now I know I can get the staffService through `serviceProvider.GetService<IStaffService>()`, it look like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IStaffService, StaffService>();

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var staffService = serviceProvider.GetService<IStaffService>();
    }
 }
```

but I'm wondering that how can I get the serviceProvider in **a new Class library** so that I can get the **staffService** in the new Class library instead of in the `Startup.cs`,does anyone can help me?

Comment: You do not need the Service Provider in your new class library, what you need is Dependency injection, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1
You need to "inject" the interface of the services you need, via the constructor of your class. Does this help?

Comment: you don't need to do `var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();` the framework will do it for you when using your `Startup`.

Comment: just inject IStaffService into your class and let framework handle that. It was created to do such things

Comment: I may kown what you mean guys, you supposed that I should pass the IStaffService into the constructor and the framework will inject this service automatic,it looks like this:
public class StaffController{
 private readonly IStaffService _staffService;
 public StaffController(IStaffService staffService){
 _staffService = staffService;
}
}
and I can use the _staffService in the controller right?

Comment: But what puzzles me is that if i have so many services in the controller and they are used in different methods,so I have to inject all the  services on constructor? What I want is that when I need a service,then I get a service through ServiceProvider,how can I do this?Does anyone can help?

Comment: The class in your library should not care how it's constructor is called. Your Startup class should register all the services, including any from other libraries. Yes that can end up being a long list, though you can write helper methods in your library to ensure all services are registered.

Comment: @Alan: If your constructor has too many dependencies, consider splitting your controller into multiple controllers that are more niche, so they only need a limited amount of dependencies. Injecting into the constructor is generally superior to using a service locator.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to do var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(); the framework will do it for you when using your Startup.cs